# Width of a block with. Horizontally-oriented website with text columns "Modern UI"-like

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve that Modern UI app look (horizontally-oriented with text columns width defined width) on my website. The only problem is text containers take too much width and I fail to make them wrap the text nicely. I need #container's height to adjust to browser size. Any suggestions?
http://jsfiddle.net/PAN_IGI/tMtup/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<!-- START #container -->
<article>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
</article>
<article>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
</article>
<article>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#container {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
}

article {
-moz-column-width: 200px;
-webkit-column-width: 200px;
column-width: 200px;
padding: 10px;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
white-space: normal;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

p {
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd set the width of the container to 100% to stop it being super wide:

```
#container {
    …
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then the individual articles are slightly too tall as you add padding. Set to box-sizing: border-box; to make the height also include the padding:

```
article {
    …
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tMtup/4/ or http://jsfiddle.net/tMtup/4/show/

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. The articles are not super wide any more, but they're still as wide as div#container, and if I add more paragraphs to them, text will overlay the adjacent article.

http://jsfiddle.net/PAN_IGI/tMtup/5/
http://jsfiddle.net/PAN_IGI/tMtup/5/show/

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted? How wide do you want container to be? You can avoid the overflow thing by adding overflow-x: scroll; http://jsfiddle.net/tMtup/6/